# Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader one column show question mark reading in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, reader, excel-reader

[image]

Please check this image ###### value showing que mark. If I upload this column value on database this value save with ??????? like.

I am using Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader in php

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("/var/www/office/office/public_html/aumfiles1/$file",true);


$folioNumber    =   addslashes(trim($data->val($j,3)));


??????????

SELECT rUnits FROM test_trans1 WHERE folioNumber='??????????' and productCode='test' and arn_id='66' and data_type='KARVY'

update test_trans1 set rUnits = '1458.747' WHERE folioNumber='??????????' and productCode='test' and arn_id='66' and data_type='KARVY'

??????????
```

Comment: length problem. increase column length or datatype

Comment: How can i add length by php code because this process is run by cron job

Comment: change into the database

Comment: Column type is varchar and value is 255, Problem in reading the column value i am trying to read this column value on xls file using php code than its show ??????? file